# How to configure the authentication way for each connector

Tags: spring-boot, http, authentication, https, connection

I woud like to do the following:

1. Create one service using Spring boot.
2. Make it possible to receive multiple http (https) accesses on different ports.

ex)
1. ClientA -----> http: // Server: 8080  -----> Service (with no Basic authentication)
2. ClientA -----> https: // Server: 8443 -----> Service (with Basic authentication)
3. ClientA -----> https: // Server: 9443 -----> Service (with no Basic authentication)

3. I do not want to use the way of specifying the port number in "application.properties".

I thought about using the following code, but I don't know how to associate "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" with "TomcatServletWebServerFactory".

I would like to know how to configure the authentication way for each connector.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("userid").password("{noop}passwd").roles("USER");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/DocumentB/**");
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.httpBasic();       // Basic authentication
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}

public class HttpsConnectorA {
    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }
    private Connector createSslConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
        try {
            connector.setScheme("https");
            connector.setSecure(true);
            connector.setPort(8443);
            protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
            protocol.setKeystoreType("PKCS12");
            protocol.setKeystoreFile("C:\\ssl\\server.p12");
            protocol.setKeystorePass("pass1");
            protocol.setKeyAlias("tomcat");
            return connector;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("can't access keystore: [" + "keystore" + "] or truststore: [" + "keystore" + "]", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The security configuration applies to your application not to specific connectors. All those connectors eventually go to the same application.

Comment: I changed the subject,thanks.